# Separate Dev and Production instances and database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a web application hosted on a server, it uses virtualEnv to separate dev and prod instances. Both instances share the same postgres database. (all on the same server)

I am kind of new to docker and I would like to replace the dev and prod instances with docker containers, and each link to its dev or prod postgres containers (or a similar effect so that a code change in development will not affect production database.)

what is the best design for this scenario? should I have the dev and prod container mapped to different ports? Can I have 1 dockerfile for both dev and prod containers? How do I deal with 2 postgres container?

Answer (score 1):

Seems your requirement is not very complicated, so I think you can run 2 pair containers (each pair have one application container and one postgres container) to achieve this, the basic structure described as below:

```
devContainer---> pgsDBContainer:<port_number1> ---> dataVolume1

prodContainer---> pgsDBContainer:<port_number2> ---> dataVolume2
```

Each container pair have one dedicated port number and one dedicated volume. The port numbers used for dev or prod application to connect to corresponding postgres database, which should be easy to understand. But volume is another story.

Please read this [Manage data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) doc for container volume. As you mentioned that `"a code change in development will not affect production database"`, which means you should have two separate volumes for postgres containers, so the data of the databases will not mixed up.

> Can I have 1 dockerfile for both dev and prod containers?

Yes you can, just as I mentioned, you should give each postgres container different port and volume config when you start them with [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#docker-run-reference) command. [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#docker-run-reference) has [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/expose-incoming-ports) option and [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) option for you to config the port number and volume location.

Just a reminder, When you run a database in container, you may need to consider the Data Persistent in container environment to avoid data loss that caused by container removed. Some discussions of container Data Persistent can be found [here](http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/) and [there](https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/docker-storage-patterns-for-persistence/).